# Get Javascript nested object property full address as string

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I would like to set DOM element ID's equal to a nested object property's full address. How to I convert an object property address to a string?

I welcome alternative means of naming a DOM element so it is clear to what object property it is referring

```
var myBowtie = {"Hazard":{"Name":"Hydrocarbons under Pressure"},
                "TopEvent":{"Name":"Loss of Containment"},
                "Cause1": {
                  "Name":"Cause 1",
                  "Barrier1": {
                    "Name":"Barrier 1",
                    "Type":null,
                    "Health":null,
                    "DegFactor1":{
                      "Name":null,
                      "Barrier1": {
                        "Name":null,
                        "Health":null
                        }
                     },
                    },
                },
                "Cause2": {
                  "Name":"Cause 2",
                  "Barrier0": {
                    "Name":"New Barrier 1",
                    "Type":null,
                    "Health":null,
                    "DegFactor1":{
                      "Name":null,
                      "Barrier1": {
                        "Name":null,
                        "Health":null
                        }
                     },
                    },
                },
                "Consequence2": {
                  "Name":"Consequence 2",
                  "Barrier1": {
                    "Name":"New Barrier 1",
                    "Type":null,
                    "Health":null,
                    "DegFactor1":{
                      "Name":null,
                      "Barrier1": {
                        "Name":null,
                        "Health":null
                        }
                     },
                    },
                },
             };

displayBowtie("Barrier",myBowtie.Cause1);

function displayBowtie(elementType,objectName){
    if (Object.entries(objectName).length > 0){ //ensure object has properties
    const Entries = Object.entries(objectName);
      for (const entry of Entries){ //loop through properties
        if (entry[0].includes(elementType)){ //loop through each property that matches the name
          //would like to have a string = "myBowtie.Cause1.Barrier1". I can then set this to a DOM element ID for accessing information later 
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is invalid, after validation it should look like below and then you can access the children easily through `.` or  `[]`

If you are sure that the name will be unique, then you can use it as `id` for html objects through `myBowtie.Cause1.Barrier1.Name`

```js
let myBowtie ={ 
   "Hazard":{ 
      "Name":"Hydrocarbons under Pressure"
   },
   "TopEvent":{ 
      "Name":"Loss of Containment"
   },
   "Cause1":{ 
      "Name":"Cause 1",
      "Barrier1":{ 
         "Name":"Barrier 1",
         "Type":null,
         "Health":null,
         "DegFactor1":{ 
            "Name":null,
            "Barrier1":{ 
               "Name":null,
               "Health":null
            }
         },

      },

   },
   "Cause2":{ 
      "Name":"Cause 2",
      "Barrier0":{ 
         "Name":"New Barrier 1",
         "Type":null,
         "Health":null,
         "DegFactor1":{ 
            "Name":null,
            "Barrier1":{ 
               "Name":null,
               "Health":null
            }
         },

      },

   },
   "Consequence2":{ 
      "Name":"Consequence 2",
      "Barrier1":{ 
         "Name":"New Barrier 1",
         "Type":null,
         "Health":null,
         "DegFactor1":{ 
            "Name":null,
            "Barrier1":{ 
               "Name":null,
               "Health":null
            }
         },

      },

   },

};

let cause1 = myBowtie.Cause1
if(cause1.hasOwnProperty("Barrier1")){
  console.log("object - " + JSON.stringify(id, null, 4))
  console.log("object name - " + id.Name)
}
else{
  console.log("myBowtie.Cause1 does not contain Barrier1 property");
}
```

Comment: ^^ happy coding xD

Answer (score 0):

The following script should be able to help you with your problem.

```
var varFind = function (predicate, object, layers) {
    //errors
    if (typeof(predicate) !== "function") {
        throw "First agrument is not a function. Example is (key, obj, path) => obj[key] == 234095843.";
    }
    if (typeof(object) !== "string") {
        throw "Second agrument is not a string. Example is \"myObj\".";
    }
    if (typeof(layers) !== "number" && layers !== undefined) {
        throw "Third agrument is not a number. Example is 15.";
    }
    var newEval = function (str) {
        try{
            return new Function("return " + str + ";")();
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //where result will be stored
    const results = [];
    //to prevent cors error
    const isElement = function (element) {
        try{
            return element instanceof Element || element instanceof HTMLDocument;
        } catch(e){
            return false;
        }   
    }
    //path finding function
    const varSearch = function (obj, path, cyclicDetect, layers) {
        //initial set up
        if(typeof(path) == "undefined") {
            path = [
                (newEval(object) || window) === window ? "window" : object
            ];
            cyclicDetect = [];
        }
        //looping through object
        for (var key of Object.keys(obj)) {
            //to prevent errors
            try {
                //layers is used more in lag reduction
                layers = typeof(layers) == "number" ? layers : Infinity;
                //pushing current key to path
                path.push(key);
                //if matches predicate
                if(predicate(key, obj, path) === true) {
                    //cloning path for modification
                    var editedPath = [...path];
                    //putting in propper formatt
                    for (var i in path) {
                        if (i != 0) {
                            editedPath[i] = "['" + editedPath[i].replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "']";
                        }
                    }
                    //pushing result to results
                    results.push(editedPath.join(""));
                }
                //to help with cyclic detection
                var isCyclic = false;
                //for easier access
                const o = obj[key];
                //testing if element to prevent cors error and if it is an object
                if (o && typeof o === "object" && !isElement(o) && layers != 0) {
                    //pushing object to cyclic detect
                    cyclicDetect.push(obj);
                    for(var i in cyclicDetect) {
                        //checking if cyclic
                        if(cyclicDetect[i] == o) {
                            isCyclic = true;
                        }
                    }
                    //recursion!
                    if (!isCyclic) {
                        varSearch(o, path, cyclicDetect, layers - 1);
                    }
                    //popping cyclicDetect for future objects not in that recursion
                    cyclicDetect.pop(obj);
                }
                //popping path for the next possible path
                path.pop();
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    //getting results
    varSearch(newEval(object) || window, undefined, undefined, layers)
    return results;
}
```

This gives more finding options, gives all objects that meet criteria, and bypasses cyclic links.

Example of use:

```
var document.getElementById("IdHere").innerHTML = varFind((key, obj, path) => key === "Barrier1", "myBowtie")[0];
```

Output in your case:

```
myBowtie['Cause1']['Barrier1']
//the reason it is using the `[]` notation is because that the object supports more characters when calling it.
```